# Azure devops pipeline on mac agent : Could not locate Gemfile when bundle install

Tags: ruby, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to install via Azure DevOps pipeline on Mac agent and i keep getting this error :
- task: CmdLine@2
inputs:
script: 'mkdir ios'

```
  - script: |
     cd ios 
     gem install bundler

     bundle update --bundler

     bundle install
     
    workingDirectory: ios
    displayName: 'Ruby bundle setup'
```

Error :

```
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5917840Z ##[section]Starting: Ruby bundle setup
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5928350Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5928740Z Task         : Command line
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5929150Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5929490Z Version      : 2.164.2
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5929750Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5930170Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-09-06T11:54:07.5930590Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-06T11:54:07.7401990Z Generating script.
2020-09-06T11:54:07.7424640Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-09-06T11:54:07.7456160Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/_temp/d9733c1e-f521-48ca-aa7c-9d3b24c88953.sh
2020-09-06T11:54:07.7526110Z /Users/runner/work/_temp/d9733c1e-f521-48ca-aa7c-9d3b24c88953.sh: line 1: cd: ios: No such file or directory
2020-09-06T11:54:12.3083310Z Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T11:54:12.3084130Z Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T11:54:12.3084780Z Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T11:54:12.3085110Z Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
2020-09-06T11:54:12.3085430Z 1 gem installed
2020-09-06T11:54:12.6954440Z Could not locate Gemfile
2020-09-06T11:54:13.1617230Z Could not locate Gemfile
2020-09-06T11:54:13.1694000Z 
2020-09-06T11:54:13.1763400Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '10'.
2020-09-06T11:54:13.1779990Z ##[section]Finishing: Ruby bundle setup
```

even if i follow this tutorial :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/ruby?view=azure-devops

i still getting :

```
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6476200Z ##[section]Starting: bundle install
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6490380Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6490780Z Task         : Command line
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6491150Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6491570Z Version      : 2.164.2
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6491830Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6492250Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2020-09-06T12:27:31.6492690Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-06T12:27:31.8007410Z Generating script.
2020-09-06T12:27:31.8038100Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-09-06T12:27:31.8070710Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/_temp/79d6c766-b735-4025-8576-a11120d84585.sh
2020-09-06T12:27:36.4057030Z Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T12:27:36.4068290Z Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T12:27:36.4073040Z Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.1.4
2020-09-06T12:27:36.4116410Z Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
2020-09-06T12:27:36.4130600Z 1 gem installed
2020-09-06T12:27:36.7989650Z Could not locate Gemfile
2020-09-06T12:27:36.8083080Z 
2020-09-06T12:27:36.8160820Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '10'.
2020-09-06T12:27:36.8177100Z ##[section]Finishing: bundle install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure devops pipeline on mac agent : Could not locate Gemfile when bundle install

According to the error message:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

It seems we do not have `Gemfile` in the workspace directory.

To resolve this issue, we need run `bundle init` first and after that `bundle install`.

As test, I add `bundle init` in your CmdLine task like following, and it works fine:

```
- script: |
   mkdir ios
   
   cd ios
   
   gem install bundler
   
   bundle init
   
   bundle update --bundler
   
   bundle install
   
  displayName: 'Ruby bundle setup'
```

The result:

[image]